# fetching list elements using jinja2 under flask app

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a list say list[a][b] of length 10.
I want to print from list[0][b] to list[10][b] and use it in [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) template.

```
{% for i in test %}
<p> {{test[i][0]}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

throws error:

```
UndefinedError: list object has no element
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You actually get the element out of the list when you iterate over it, not the index value:

```
{% for row in test %}
    {# Note that we subscript `row` directly,
    (rather than attempting to index `test` with `row`) #}
    <p>{{ row[0] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Cheers! This did the trick! . I am wondering why such things are not mentioned in documentation. or is it mentioned and I haven't noticed it?

Comment: @ChandanGupta - in this case, the behavior is shared by Python itself and so isn't *terribly* surprising (hence, no doc mention, aside from mentioning in the docs for `for` that it "loops over each item in the sequence" - in Python *many* things are iterable). :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make sure to always have the first 10:

```
{% for test in tests[0:10] %}
<p> {{ test[1] }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```